# How to force chrome session without extensions from HTML or JS?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

I develop a system which will use a browser as UI client. However users tend to install different extensions (plugins) into browser. Many extensions are able to access page contents, manipulate them, send them to remote servers. So I see browser extensions as a security risk.

**Question:** is it possible to force a plugin-less session? At least for a URL I specify?

Comment: The only "solution" is to render the content server-side as a picture in a canvas element.

Comment: This will not protect from page screenshots.